# Norton op-amps advantages

Tags: operational-amplifier, transimpedance, norton

I have been reading about Norton operational amplifiers, I got a good idea of how they work, even at the transistor level, I understand that difference current input = voltage output.

What I have been having trouble with is finding out about the advantages of these op-amps VS the traditional voltage ones, is it speed, bandwidth, what?

Where should one use a Norton op-amp instead of a regular voltage op-amp? I ask this because if it's a matter of applications in which the output is a current (like in a DAC) one can still use regular voltage op-amps, for example, an inverting transimpedance amplifier with its input as a virtual ground.

Two example data sheets are [LM3900](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3900.pdf) and [LM359](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm359.pdf).

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOy2Zr_kKIM) explains fairly well how a Norton (Current Differencing Amp) works. Look at 19:30 on the video.

However again, I need to know in which applications this op-amp is best, and what should drive me to use a Norton op-amp instead of a voltage op-amp.

Comment: Can you link to a datasheet for an example of the kind of part you're asking about?

Comment: Just added 2 datasheets at the end of my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To be completely frank, the main commercial application of LM3900 is analog music synthesis. It is an excellent chip for this application, since the application doesn't take much precision - the sound is adjusted on the fly by a human - but the current inputs make it easy to interoperate with various other current-controlled circuits that are somewhat ubiquitous in analog music synthesis.

> I need to know in which applications this op-amp is best, and what should drive me to use a Norton op-amp instead of a voltage op-amp.

Retro-inspired analog designs done for fun, and analog music synthesis are... about it. A wonderful part to mess about with - due to its imperfections it's more challenging to use, but to someone with "analog chops" it should be a source of endless enjoyment. Other than that - not really much genuine need for it today. TI, if you're listening: please keep making it so I won't feel old. Thank you!

LM359 is a much faster part and can find commercial practical use - but since it's not exactly a part you'll be taught about extensively in most EE programs, there are relatively few people who care enough to figure out when it might be of use. Modern voltage-feedback op-amps, along with small surface mount components, are usually perfectly capable in whatever application you might have used LM359 back in the day. If you're designing a retro computing video circuit, LM359 is wonderful part!

Answer (score 0):

A norton opamp works with currents, you use one if you want to find the difference between two currents, then use a Norton operation amplifier. Even the Norton opamp outputs a voltage.

Most applications and sensors don't use currents as a signal carrier. Using current usually means burning up power. One problem is many sensors are resistive and this also creates problems if you wanted to subtract currents to find the difference between them. I can't think of a reason to use a Norton op amp and subtract two currents (which is probably why you don't see them all that often), all of the examples in the link below show the Norton opamps being used to convert the Norton opamp to a voltage opamp.

> The LM3900 is a 14-pin DIP containing four identical op-amps, each
>   with inverting and noninverting inputs and an output. However, these
>   op-amps are very different from the usual op-amp, and must be used in
>   a completely different way. The usual op-amp responds to a
>   differential voltage at its inputs, but the LM3900 responds to a
>   differential current. Instead of a differential amplifier, the input
>   stage is the current-differencing circuit shown at the right. The
>   current mirror at the noninverting input subtracts the current at that
>   input, I+, from the current at the inverting input, I-, to form the
>   difference current I- - I+ that is furnished to the amplifier with
>   overall gain of 70 dB. If I- is greater than I+, the output saturates
>   low, and if I- is less, the output saturates high. Feedback from the
>   output to the inverting input acts to reduce the difference current,
>   which in normal operation is very small. This is just like the usual
>   op-amp, except with current instead of voltage. The output, however,
>   is a voltage as with the usual op-amp. The label "Norton" refers to
>   the Norton equivalent circuit for a current source.

Source: https://mysite.du.edu/~etuttle/electron/elect21.htm

Comment: "all of the examples in the link below show the Norton opamps being used to convert the Norton opamp to a voltage opamp.", Yes thats why I dont understand what are the advantages of such amp.

Comment: That's because there are no advantages to the modern opamp. In 1984 there may have been

Comment: The big advantage of a Norton OP is its high bandwidth. This is due to the current subtraction right in the input stage, even before the first transistor. Only the current difference ever gets amplified. See both the internal schematic of the LM359 and the LM3900.

Comment: @Janka Thanks!! If I could up your comment twice, I'd do it. That was the first thing I was looking to see in Spike's answer and missed seeing.

Comment: High bandwidth as in unity gain around 10MHz? There are opamps that do 100MHz now

Comment: So, bottomline, is there any reason to use a Norton amp these days?

Comment: I don't think so, the impedance is also much lower than modern amps as you need to use resistors for the inputs.

Comment: Looks to me like the current-feedback amplifier might be the modern version of this. They have much wider bandwidths and substantially higher slew rates than conventional op amps, mostly independent of gain (as opposed to the gain-bandwidth product of a regular op amp).

Comment: @Hearth - Right on the money! The current feedback op-amp has all the same benefits of a Norton op-amp but has the benefit of high input impedance for the non-inverting input. This allows the design of very high bandwidth buffer amplifiers that do not significantly load down the signal source the way that Norton op-amps do.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of Norton amps such as the LM3900 is that that they are designed to work from a single supply, which makes them easy to use in equipment that is battery powered, in vehicles, or as an add-on circuit to existing single supply equipment.
The LM3900 is popular in amateur radio projects for just this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Another under-appreciated quality of Norton and other current-feedback amps with voltage outputs is that they are trans-impedance amplifiers, and this makes them useful for some mathematical processing that otherwise can be awkward with voltage-feedback op-amps. They are also natural candidates for monitoring some control interfaces (e.g. 4-20mA controls).